# Nested ng-repeat for creating table <TD> rendering very slowly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a newbie in AngularJS. My dynamic UI (html table) look like as follows.

```
ID | Name | CardNo |26 |27 |28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 1 | 2 |3 | 11 |12...........|25   

1     A        001           p    p    P    p   p   P           p
```

My Json format looks like

var empAttendance = [
{
    id: 1,
    cardNo: "001",
    name: "A",
    attendance: [
        { "id": 1, "day": 28 }, { "id": 2, "day": 29}, { "id": 3, "day": 30 },
        { "id": 4, "day": 31 }, { "id": 5, "day": 2 }, { "id": 5, "day": 12 }
      ]
  }];

dtRange = [26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3...............................25];

View (html):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th> 
      <th>CardNo</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      th data-ng-repeat="dt in vm.dtRange">{{dt}}</th>                                     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="p in vm.employeeAtt">
        <td>{{p.id}}</td>
        <td>{{p.cardNo}}</td>
        <td>{{p.name}}</td>
        <td data-ng-repeat="dt in vm.dtRange">
          <span data-ng-repeat="att in p.attendance" ng-if="dt == att.day">P</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

It seems, One employee has many attendance withing date range (column header). And I tried to put 'P' into the td cell according to the day value and by matching column header. I do not need any pagination and will load all the filtered employee list associated attendances.

However, the above logic working as expected. But " rendering very very slowly. Even I commented the inner line 'P'.

My minimum number of employee is 500 and maximum 3000. I also tried with cache data and made sure the rendering slowness. I did put limitto in ng-repeat. but still no significant performance change.

Any idea would be really helpful to me. I am using Angularjs 1.5.0

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with Angular and large data sets. Unfortunately, there is not a lot you can do to change the behavior, but you can speed it up if you are willing to give up some functionality.

Really the issue is that all of this data is being bound. Does this form need to have live updates? Or are you only displaying it? If you have 500 employees, and your date range is 30 days, that's already 15,000 watchers! Plus you are adding in more watchers with your `<span>` tags. On top of that you are performing a conditional evaluation!

I would suggest displaying this data statically. This is a good library for doing that:
https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

It allows you to forgo the watchers if you don't need them and still display your data using the ng-repeat approach.

If you absolutely *must* have your data bound, because you are doing live updates or something, you should really consider paginating your results. This will dramatically reduce the number of watchers.

Here is another great resource for tine tuning your page for performance.
https://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will consider the issues that you mentioned.